# How to display mysql result in a modal bootstrap after a form is submitted

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, form-submit

I'm searching for a solution to display a mysql result in a modal box. Saying I'm going to make a voting form. Which is the user choose an option and click submit. After a submit is clicked, a modal box is called and display the number of vote they just chosen.

I'm looking for this kinda example everywhere but no result. I'm wondering if there's any one of them on the planet. So could you guy please suggest or give me an idea how to achieve this.

Comment: This would be more of a JavaScript question.. are you using jQuery? If not, I'd highly recommend it for this.

Comment: Nick, the bootstrap is based on jQuery by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data as shown in script below upon form post if you calculate the number of votes in php or you can query the database in your popup using the id for which you need total votes, so in this case you will need to pass id only.

```
//This script reads the itema id and votes using class open-AddBookDialog and add the values //to input fields id and votes in modal box
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".open-AddBookDialog").click(function () { 

         $('#id').val($(this).data('id'));  
         $('#votes').val($(this).data('votes'));

        $('#myModal_3').modal('show');
    });
});
</script>

// your button
 <input type="button" class="open-AddBookDialog"  data-votes="<?php echo $votes;?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" role="button" data-toggle="modal" />

//Modal box
<div id="myModal_3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
       <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" >Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
             <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value=""/>
          <input type="text" name="votes" id="votes" value=""/> </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="send" value="Send">
        </div>
        </div>


        </form>
           <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>   
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Cartina, Thank you for your code. but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I just want a form which is pass the value to modal right after a submit button is clicked.

Comment: @wilf this example is to demonstrate how we pass value from form to modal. The script at the top of the page picks value from button using class and set it to a hidden field in modal.